# Why would a bot submit a sign up form with fake info?

Tags: web-crawlers, registration, spamming

I have a sign up form where people can enter their name and address, then click on a submit button.

However I am getting BOTs entering sign up details and submitting the form - or at least I presume it is a BOT, the user agent is "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1" which seems ok, but the name is something like "5914f968f3ea6" and they did not confirm their email address immediately (I deleted the accounts when I noticed this, so it is now too late to confirm their email address on the off chance they are a real person).

I have had 4 BOT entries, so I was just wondering ... why would anyone have a BOT that submits fake sign ups?

Comment: These are spam bots.